If i click on age in date and time column of transform tab in power query editor, instead of inserted age i am getting extracted age?
If i click on age in date option of date and time column of transform tab in power query editor, instead of getting a new column calculated as age(inserted age) i am getting extracted age?
I mean a new column was being created in older version of power Bi but, now it is showing extracted age?
I am expecting to get a new column to it.

Do not select the Age in the Transform menu. Please try the age function in the Add Column Menu. Then you will get a new column.

